# What data type would I need to set for a field in a table, that restricts the values from a set of options?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I have a bunch of fields in my table that are standard datatypes such as varchar, INT, etc.

I do have a field that I want to have restricted to one of four options only, but I'm not sure what datatype I would need here? Or is there even a datatype for this? So if I want a field to only be able to take from a fixed set of values say "In progress", "Completed", "Not started", and "Canceled", like you could enforce via a dropdown list in Excel, how would I make that happen?

I tried searching on Google and YouTube but couldn't find anything specific to my question. I feel this is odd because even Microsoft Access has a dropdown/option datatype last I remember. So I'm obviously unaware of the basics and am looking for some help.

Comment: Take a look at [ENUMs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the `ENUM` data type. For example:

```
create table task (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  status enum ('In progress', 'Completed', 'Not started', 'Canceled')
);

insert into task (id, name, status) values (12, 'Pet Dog', 'Not started'); -- succeeds
insert into task (id, name, status) values (15, 'Pay Internet', 'Pending'); -- fails
```

**EDIT**:

However, the solution above forces the status to be *static*. If later on you needed toadd an extra status you would need to modify the table structure. Not great.

If you wanted to have dynamic status all the while they are fully validated, you can use a foreign key. For example:

```
create table task_status (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50),
  unique (name)
);

insert into task_status (id, name) values 
  (1, 'In progress'),
  (2, 'Completed'),
  (3, 'Not started'),
  (4, 'Canceled');

create table task (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  status int not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (status) references task_status (id)
);

insert into task (id, name, status) values (12, 'Pet Dog', 3); -- succeeds
insert into task (id, name, status) values (15, 'Pay Internet', null); -- fails
insert into task (id, name, status) values (15, 'Buy Cat', 5); -- fails
```

But if I add the new status "Pending":

```
insert into task_status (id, name) values (5, 'Pending');
insert into task (id, name, status) values (15, 'Buy Cat', 5); -- succeeds!
```